# IF statement in MySQL stored function goes wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

I get a error on line 12 (at the endif statement).
I belief I´m doing something wrong within the IF or ELSE, can anyone help me?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION TEST (`param` INT) 
RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE `var` INT;

    SET `var` = 1;

    IF `param` > 0 THEN
        SET `var` = `var` + `param`;
    END IF;

    RETURN `var`;
END$$
```

EDIT: (same function with case instead of if, same problem)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION TEST (`param` INT) 
RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE `var` INT;

    SET `var` = 1;

    SET `var` = 
        CASE
            WHEN `param` > 0 THEN `var` + `param` ELSE `var`
        END ;

    RETURN `var`;
END$$
```

Comment: Can you use `set` statements inside `if-else` conditional?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: yes, you can. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

Comment: what is your point here: `SET var = var;` ?

Answer (score 7):

Try this instead:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE `var` INT;

    SET var = 
      CASE
        WHEN param > 0 THEN var + 1 ELSE var 
      END ;

    RETURN var;
END$$
```

Comment: `+1` for using case. :D by the way, why do you need to set the value of `var` from `var`?

Comment: @JohnWoo I am not familier with mysql syntax but these ```` are hurting my eyes this why I removed it.

Comment: No that's not what i mean. Can it possibly `SET var = 
      CASE WHEN param > 0 THEN var + 1 END ;` ?

Comment: @JohnWoo I think no because `ELSE` will return `NULL` as far as I now. Thats why I used `ELSE var` if you omit it it will be `NULL` in case `param` was `<= 0`

Comment: Don't mind the param > 0, it's just a made up statement. But the issue lays in the END. It still gives an error in both cases.

Comment: The main thing I like to do is to check
IF statement is true THEN set var + 1 (some int) END IF;
But my statement keeps on tripping over de END in the END IF.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 28

Comment: @pascalvgemert, Please edit your question with the updated query you are currently using which gives you that error. Thanks

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I did, the case of the if statement makes no differents.

Comment: @pascalvgemert So when you used the `CASE` expression instead of `IF` the is still presented no difference right? If so please add the updated query with the `CASE` expression that gave you that error.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal still gives the error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 15

Answer (score 1):

Found out it was a bug in PHPMyAdmin, if I added the function with 'add routine' it worked!